# Core Data query 1<-->>2<<-->3. How get 1 from 3?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

For example I have data model like this

```
Entity: Store                     Entity: Inventory           Entity:Product
Attribute: name                   Attribute: qty              Attribute: name
Relationship: inventories <---->>   Relationsips:  <<---->    Relationship: inventories
                                         stores 
                                        products
```

I wanna know how retrieve from Core Data list of Stores for exact Product. 
I have tableView with products and on click on exact product cell I wanna move to another controller with list of stores which contatins this product.

As I understand I can get NSSet of all Inventory entities first and iterate it to fetch stores. But I think Core Data is more intelligent thing and more simple and elegant method exists for it. For example, maybe when I get all inventory objects I can fetch Store with predicate somethink like this "Store.inventories IN  (array of my inventories from previous fetch)". Or even more simple way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Core Data - as a general rule - when you have a managed object in your hands, start with that object and navigate the model to retrieve related entities. Specifically:

```
// if @"stores" is the name of the relationship in Inventory:
NSSet *stores = [product.inventories valueForKey:@"stores"];
```